# Getting identity for type parameter?

Tags: haskell, monoids

I have the following type that i want to be an instance of `Monoid` typeclass.I do not know how to set a  parametrized field to the identity.Is there any way when using parametrized type to get the identity of that type ?

```
data Tree a=Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) |Empty deriving (Eq,Show)

instance Monoid Tree where
    mempty=Empty
    mappend a Empty=a
    mappend a b=Node (identity) x y
```

As you can see i need the simple field to be set to the identity of the parameter type.

Example

```
mappend::Tree Int
mappend (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)=Node 0 (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)

mappend::Tree []
mappend (Leaf [1,2])(Leaf [2,3])=Node [] (Leaf [1,2])(Leaf [2,3])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can only happen if `a` itself is a `Monoid` type as well, so we can write this as:

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Tree a) where
    mempty = Empty
    mappend Empty a = a
    mappend a Empty = a
    mappend a b = Node mempty a b
```

The above will not work for an `Int`, since an `Int` is not a `Monoid`. There are two very popular candidates *(ℕ, +, 0)*, and *(ℕ, ×, 1)*. You can however make use of [**`Sum`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) which is the representation of the former monoid.

The `mempty` in the body of the last line is thus *not* the `mempty` we are defining, but the `mempty` of type `a`.

That being said, if you define a `Monoid Tree` like that, it means that you consider a `Node mempty (Node mempty a b) c == Node mempty a (Node mempty b c)`, since this is required by the *monoid laws*. So the `deriving Eq` is not completely in "*harmony*" here with the `mappend`. The `mappend` operator (in mathematics typically denoted as *⊕*), should satisfy the condition *∀ a,b,c∈ S: a⊕(b⊕c) = (a⊕b)⊕c*.

You either should implement `Eq` yourself differently, or you should try to come up with another structure for your monoid.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but it's far too long for a comment. As Willem Van Onsem suggests, your `Monoid` instance isn't lawful. I suspect you probably want one of two things:

#### A free magma

The free magma over a type can be defined

```
data Magma a = Branch (Magma a) (Magma a) | Leaf a | Empty
  deriving Show
```

This isn't naturally a monoid, but it's sometimes useful to *pretend* it's one:

```
instance Monoid (Magma a) where
  mempty = Empty
  mappend = Branch

-- For recent GHC, add this instance
instance Semigroup (Magma a) where
  (<>) = Branch
```

This can be used with a fold to gain insight into the structure of that fold. To get a sense of how this works, compare the results of applying `foldMap Leaf` to `[1..20]`, `Data.Sequence.fromList [1..20]`, and `Data.Set.fromList [1..20]`.

#### A (particular) free monad

Consider generalizing your tree to allow different types in the internal nodes than in the leaves:

```
data Tree a b = Node a (Tree a b) (Tree a b) | Leaf b
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

(This turns out to be the free monad over the functor `Tree a`, defined

```
data TreeF a b = NodeF a b b
```

but we don't really need to get into the details of what that means.)

The monad operation for the `Tree a` monad is a sort of "grafting", where the leaves are replaced by trees.

```
instance Functor (Tree a) where
  fmap f (Leaf b) = Leaf (f b)
  fmap f (Node a l r) = Node a (fmap f l) (fmap f r)

instance Applicative (Tree a) where
  pure = Leaf
  (<*>) = ap
  liftA2 = liftM2

instance Monad (Tree a) where
  Leaf b >>= f = f b
  Node a l r >>= f = Node a (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
```

You can think of `>>=` as supporting a sort of vertical appending, where the tree grows downward from its leaves.